# How can I fix this issue with my table?

Tags: html-table, position, label, border, cell

I'm trying to replicate a one rowed table with a form, such that when I press the '+' button - I would like another table form to drop down below it exactly the way it is - however, when I do that and add the same element as the table with the HTML code, I get something different...

I got screenshot images to the form below and after that I got the code indented -

[image: http://i58.tinypic.com/ruy7pv.png]

[image: http://i57.tinypic.com/dbp0y.png]

The code for the above images is listed below - the first being the forms and the second being the Javascript function

```
    <body>
        <form>

            <div id="container1">

<table border="1" cellspacing="0" style="margin-top:12px width="900"">
<colgroup>
<col span="1">
</colgroup>
<tr>
<td valign="top">
<label for="company" size="3">Company:</label> <input type="text" id="company" name="company" maxlength="15" size="15">
</td>
<td valign="top">
<label for="position1" size="3">Position:</label> <input  type="text" id="position1" name="position1" maxlength="20" size="12"> </td> <td valign="top"><label for="tasks" size="3"> Tasks: </label></td><td> <textarea  id="tasks" name="tasks" maxlength="1000" cols="25" rows="1"></textarea></td>
<td valign="top"><label for="from1" size="3">  From: </label><input type="text" id="from1" name="from1" size="4" ></td> <td valign="top">To: <input type="text" id="to1" name="to1" size="4"> <td valign="top"><label for="location" size="3">Work Location: </label><input type="text" id="location" name="location" size="20" maxlength="25"><a href="#" id="Add1" onclick="aFields1()"> + </a><br></td>
</tr>
</table><br>               
            </div>

        </form>
    </body>
```

the javascipt code is posted below:

```
function aFields1(){
var container1 = document.getElementById("container1");
var table = document.createElement("table");

table.border=1; 
table.cellspacing=0;
var tr = document.createElement("tr");
var td = document.createElement("td");
td.valign = "top";

var label = document.createElement("label");
label.for = "company";
label.size = 3;
container1.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Company: "));
container1.appendChild(label);

var company = document.createElement("input");
company.type = "text";

company.id = "company";
company.name = "company";
company.size = 15;
company.maxlenth = 15;
```

//append the company input element to the td element
    td.appendChild(company);

```
tr.appendChild(td);
table.appendChild(tr);
```

//append the td element to the container1 element

```
//container1.appendChild(tr);   
container1.appendChild(table);
```

Can anyone please tell me why the table is not showing up?

There should be a border with at least one cell with the company label and input bar INSIDE it - but as you can see from the image the Company label is on the top and the input bar with the border is below it...

where'd I go wrong? and why are the borders for the cell much much more different from what came out of the HTML code?

Comment: Is the desired behavior that each time the user presses "+" they would see a new table added? Or just a new TR added to the existing table?

Comment: With your current code you are make more tables. Are you wanting to extend the original table or make a lot of one row tables?

Comment: a new tr added to the existing table - just an extra one row table - i prefer a new TR added

Comment: what is better? an extended table or just a whole lot of one row tables?

Comment: just extend that current table...saves a lot of white space

Answer (score 0):

Part of the problem is that you're appending the `label` element to the DIV directly instead of appending it to the new `td`. This is why it's showing up outside of the Table.

From your last comment, it seems like what you **really** want to do is just append a cloned TR to the existing table. Ok, there are multiple ways to do this. You can completely re-build a duplicate tr in javascript, OR you can just clone the first table row and append it to the table. This is trivial with jQuery, but can be done with pure javascript.

First, let's add an `id` attribute to the table element. like so:

```
<table id="my_table" border="1" cellspacing="0" style="margin-top:12px;width:900px">
.....snip rest of your table....
</table>
```

Then your javascript cloning can work like this (note: code is untested):

```
function aFields1() {
    var table, tr, cloned_row, inputs_to_clear;

    // find the table
    table = document.getElementById('my_table');

    // find the first tr element
    tr = table.querySelectorAll('tr')[0];

    // clone the first tr using deep = true option to copy all children
    tr_cloned = tr.cloneNode(true);

    // NOTE: the values in the cloned row will already be prefilled, so you probably want to clear input-field values as well
    inputs_to_clear = tr_cloned.querySelectorAll('input');
    foreach (var input in inputs_to_clear) {
        inputs_to_clear[input].value = '';
    }

    // append the new row
    table.appendChild(cloned_row);
}
```

Comment: so what do i gotta do then?

Comment: i did that...no changes so far yet

Comment: any one willing to help out here?

Comment: I edited my answer with a possible solution. i didn't test it in a browser, so there might be a typo. it gives the general idea of one way to solve your issue.

Comment: it doesn't work...can u check with my code again? i tried the method u asked for...flopped

Comment: it don't work amigo!...can u try it with my code in real time and lemme know then?

Comment: Why don't you create a new jsfiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/) with your HTML and Javascript, and we can hack on it together.

Comment: Jose, are you still working on this bug? Sorry I missed your earlier messages!